# ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression

Tags: flutter

Often when rendering from a list, I see Flutter throwing the following, from beneath example, see PositionedTilesState:

```
ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'tiles'. 
ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression '[     '. 
ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'StatelessColorfulTile'. 
ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'PositionedTilesState'.
```

Have you see this, and found a solution?

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:example/dart/concepts/color/unique_color_generator.dart';

// PositionedTiles
class PositionedTiles extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? title;
  const PositionedTiles({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => PositionedTilesState();
}

// PositionedTilesState
class PositionedTilesState extends State<PositionedTiles> {
  List<Widget> tiles = [
    StatelessColorfulTile(),
    StatelessColorfulTile(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(children: tiles),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: const Icon(Icons.sentiment_very_satisfied), onPressed: swapTiles),
    );
  }

  swapTiles() {
    setState(() {
      tiles.insert(1, tiles.removeAt(0));
    });
  }
}

// StatelessColorfulTile
class StatelessColorfulTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color myColor = UniqueColorGenerator.getColor();

  StatelessColorfulTile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: myColor, child: const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(70.0)));
  }
}
```

Comment: We have a similar problem in a newly started web project, and we don't know the reason for this error message... but it doesn't influence the execution of the program either. In our case the logs only appear in debug mode

Comment: In my case I cannot debug correctly, since I cannot see the runtime values , so it affects me greatly, try downgrading chrome, I do not know if this works
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71521564/chromeproxyservice-failed-to-evaluate-expression-handleprimarypointer-intern

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'handlePrimaryPointer':InternalError: No frame with index 45](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71521564/chromeproxyservice-failed-to-evaluate-expression-handleprimarypointerinterna)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there was an issue between Chrome (above version 100) and Flutter (below version 2.10.5).

**How to fix it?** Check your flutter version in terminal with `flutter --version`. If it is below 2.10.5, you can get the most recent Flutter with terminal with `flutter upgrade`

After upgrading flutter to 3.0.0 all works for me now.
I followed this issue [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/101224) and this answer on [SA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71966463/498201)

Comment: Hi, I have same problem. But i have chrome 103 and flutter 3.0.5. How i can solve this problem?

Comment: Also, i tried to downgrade Chrome to 99, and problem still yet here

Comment: Still having this problem, and I'm at Chrome 107 and Flutter 3.4.0.

Answer (score 2):

Error with Firebase_core _Web

ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression '

FirebaseCore': InternalError: Expression evaluation in async frames is not supported. No frame with index 14..

here is the solution by yurrpt Arda
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9934

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (kIsWeb) {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: const FirebaseOptions(
       apiKey: "",
       authDomain: "",
       databaseURL: "", // **DATABASEURL MUST BE GIVEN.**
       projectId: "",
       storageBucket: "",
       messagingSenderId: "",
       appId: ""),  
  );
} else {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
```