# "ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression" error

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

I get this error when I want to start my project with chrome device via flutter.

The error is as follows;
[image]

And vs code redirects to this line ;
[image]

Because of these errors chrome emulator stays on white screen (not working).
How do I fix this problem?

Comment: try downgrading chrome, I do not know if this works
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71521564/chromeproxyservice-failed-to-evaluate-expression-handleprimarypointer-intern

Comment: I don't really want to add this as an answer when it's so vague, but I ran into this with Flutter 3.0.3 and Chrome 103.0.5060.53, and just restarting my debug session fixed it. Might have been unique to my code, or a new problem in the versions of the apps, but it felt worth mentioning.

Answer (score 3):

There were some issues with debugging in Chrome after updating to Chrome v100 which have been fixed in Flutter v2.10.5 that may solve these issues:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Hotfixes-to-the-Stable-Channel#2105-april-18-2022

> [flutter/101224](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/101224) - Flutter web debugger fails when using chrome 100 or greater.

Comment: i'm still getting this as of this writing when i run debugging on Flutter Web

Comment: This issues is several years old - if you're seeing similar issues today on a recent version of Flutter/Chrome, I would file an issue on GitHub with the complete error and steps to reproduce. Thanks!