# Failed to evaluate expression 'handlePrimaryPointer':InternalError: No frame with index 45

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Code that I have written for Admin Login:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FirebaseServices {
  static Future<DocumentSnapshot> adminSignIn(id) async {
    var res =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("admin").doc(id).get();
    return res;
  }
}
```

I am getting errors are given below:

```
+ ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 
 'handlePrimaryPointer':InternalError: No frame with index 45.
+ ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression
 'postAcceptSlopTolerance': InternalError: No frame with index 45.
+ ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'FirebaseFirestore':    
  InternalError: No frame with index 32.
+ ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'DocumentSnapshot':    
  InternalError: No frame with index 32.
+ ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'Future': 
  InternalError: No frame with index 32.
+ ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'catch': 
  InternalError: No frame with index 32.
```

You can also visit [the repository of the project](https://github.com/SeAliijaz/Eco-Buy).

I tried to run `flutter doctor -v`. And then:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1706], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.0.1 at C:\flutter_windows_2.2.3-stable\flutter      
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision fb57da5f94 (2 weeks ago), 2022-05-19 15:50:29 -0700
    • Engine revision caaafc5604
    • Dart version 2.17.1
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Ali_ijaz\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components      

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio2
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    X Unable to determine bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[√] VS Code (version 1.67.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Ali_ijaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.42.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • SM G955F (mobile) • 192.168.39.10:5555 • android-arm64  • Android 7.0 (API 24)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows            • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1706]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome             • web-javascript • Google Chrome 102.0.5005.63
    • Edge (web)        • edge               • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 102.0.1245.30

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For others searching for this issue and coming across this page: I was hitting a similar error, unrelated to Firebase, and the solution was what's captured in [Benno's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71782627/5225270) but a bit buried in the details.

This error message was a red herring in my case. What was actually happening is that I had another error (did not set up CORS policy correctly), which caused the main thread to crash and then causing an async call to not get captured. Once I fixed the other error, all was working as expected.

I missed that detail originally in Benno's response and hope to save time for others (and thank you Benno!).

Answer (score 11):

If you are unable to add debug break-points and view the state of variables in the debugger, this is caused by a recent Flutter bug and you can apply the fixes down one paragraph.

If debugging works just fine, keep in mind that `ChromeProxyService` error messages are *expected after your program was paused on a break point or unhandled exception* if Async code was still executing at the time. It tells us Async code tried and of course failed to talk to the paused main thread after a debug break point or crash occurred first (Async task failed successfully). The resulting `ChromeProxyService` errors are a red herring.
Your VSCode debugger shows a red pop-up over functions that result in an unhandled exception, that's your next clue.

**If debugging break points are broken:**
Upgrade to Flutter v3.0.0 or downgrade to v2.10.4 using the workaround further down.

> Flutter 3 upgrade:
>
> Run `flutter channel stable` followed by `flutter upgrade --force`

For older versions of Flutter, a workaround is documented here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/101224#issuecomment-1092324782:

> `flutter downgrade v2.10.4`
>
> (Find Flutter install dir using: `flutter doctor -v`)
>
> `cd <path to flutter install dir>/flutter/packages/flutter_tools`
>
> update `dwds` constraint
> in packages/flutter_tools/pubspec.yaml to `11.5.2`
>
> run `flutter pub get` in packages/flutter_tools directory
>
> remove your cache: `rm -rf ../../bin/cache`
>
> rebuild flutter: `flutter pub get` in packages/flutter_tools directory (it
> triggers the flutter rebuild)

This issue caused VS Code to show no local variables when debugging my Flutter project using the web-javascript renderer. I was not able to view the error message until switching the debug option to "Debug my code + packages".

Downgrading Google Chrome to version 99.0.4844.74 also works around the issue.

Comment: It does'nt work for me! Any other solution?

Comment: In my case, version 2.10.5 does not fix it.

Comment: @Dabbel The issue re-appeared on v2.10.5 for me yesterday after the latests Chrome update. Downgrading to Flutter v2.10.4 and re-applying the work-around fixed the issue for me. Today I upgraded to Flutter v3.0.0 and also working fine.

Comment: @Benno it is not working for me

Comment: @Aliijaz Can you post the output of `flutter doctor -v` for more context please?

Comment: @Benno Now Check question again i have made some edits

Comment: @Aliijaz the `ChromeProxyService` error message you referred to will always appear in the debug console when your program is paused on a break point or unhandled exception while other Async code is still executing in the background. 

If you are able to add debug break-points and view variables in the debugger,  the `ChromeProxyService` error is a red herring for sure.

Comment: fix for me: flutter clean, flutter pub get

Answer (score 3):

This issue was addressed in the hotfix v2.10.5 of the stable branch

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Hotfixes-to-the-Stable-Channel#2105-april-18-2022

https://twitter.com/FlutterReleases/status/1516140054183387140?t=ljVpMAzd2-VfYhYeB1S52w&s=19

So flutter upgrade should work

Comment: No it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading your flutter project to a higher version, this seems like a flutter problem than your code.

I have seen some funny errors like this, if flutter clean+ restart doesn't work then I upgrade the project.

Comment: I've tried it wasn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error debugging flutter for web in chrome.  `ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression '...':InternalError: No frame with index ...`

Turns out I was parsing a string incorrectly and an exception was being thrown in an async method.  For whatever reason my IDE was breaking in `browser_client.dart` with this obscure message.

Running the same code as a windows desktop app revealed the actual error immediately.

Comment: I'll check and give you feedback ASAP.

Comment: Any update on it @Aliijaz

Comment: `flutter upgrade` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Updated from 3.3.2 to 3.3.3 and it strarted working for windows app but not for chrome.

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked after doing the following:

1. `flutter doctor` - to check if everything is ok there (no prob for me)
2. `flutter upgrade` and restart. Didn't help.
3. `flutter clean`
4. `flutter pub get`

Tadaa! It worked.

I also found a change in my env.dart file regarding feature flags that I didn't do manually.

Now running on version 3.3.9, channel stable.

Answer (score 0):

Run `flutter channel stable` followed by `flutter upgrade --force`

Comment: Sure I'll do and give you feedback

Comment: `flutter upgrade` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to 3.7.12 from 3.7.8. No change. I have an `initAsync` in `main` and a check of `Platform.iOS || Platform.Android` so that I can prompt for file storage and photo permissions.

Returning from `initAsync` before checking `Platform.iOS` prevented the bug. So I added the code for a web check:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;
```

and then do `if (kIsWeb) return;` before looking at `Platform.iOS`. That fixed it.

So before with the problem:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initAsync();
  }

  Future<void> initAsync() async {
    PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();

    setState(() {
      _version = packageInfo.version;
      _buildNumber = packageInfo.buildNumber;      
    });

    if (Platform.isIOS || Platform.isAndroid) { etc...
```

and after with the fix:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initAsync();
  }

  Future<void> initAsync() async {
    PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();

    setState(() {
      _version = packageInfo.version;
      _buildNumber = packageInfo.buildNumber;      
    });

    if (kIsWeb) return;

    if (Platform.isIOS || Platform.isAndroid) {
```