# A value of type 'int' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'

Tags: string, flutter, dart, textfield, dart-null-safety

A value of type 'int' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'String'.

```
TextFormField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    controller: TextEditingController()
                      ..text = '${profileModel.phonenumber}',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 17,
                      letterSpacing: 1,
                    ),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: "Phone Number",
                      hintText: "enter your phonenumber",
                      floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto,
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.phone),
                      focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                    onChanged: (text) {
                      number = text as int;
                      print(number);
                    },
                  ),
```

CastError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast)

```
onChanged: (text) {
 number = text as int;
 print(number);
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TextFormField(
     keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      controller: TextEditingController()
      ..text = '${profileModel.phonenumber}',
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this :

```
onChanged: (text) {
 number = int.parse(text);
 print(number);
},
```

need to change  `number = text as int;`  to  `number = int.parse(text);`

Comment: ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression '_primaryCompleter': InternalError: No frame with index 14.

Comment: Seeems to be  flutter version related issue : check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71521564/chromeproxyservice-failed-to-evaluate-expression-handleprimarypointerinterna

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend using `int.tryParse`. Because it can fail on parser too when the input text will not number. If `number` is not nullable, provide a default value.

```dart
number = int.tryParse(text)?? 0;
```

And if `number` is string just  do

```dart
  number = text;
```