# Flutter error: ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'reasonPhrase'

Tags: flutter, dart, http, https

I am making a flutter app that can request a post or get on a website it works on google website but not on mine.

I tried this example from pub dev

```
    Future<void> sendPost(String path, String hashMap) async {
        switch (hashMap) {
            case 'getArtifactData':
                var url = Uri.https(
                        'www.googleapis.com', '/books/v1/volumes', {'q': '{http}'});
                var response = await http.get(url);
                if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                    setState(() {
                        _scanBarcode = response.body;
                    });
                } else {
                    _scanBarcode = 'Response status: ${response.statusCode}';
                }
                print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
                print('Response body: ${response.body}');
                break;

            default:
                null;
        }
    }
```

but when I change the url, path, and body it doesn't work.

```
    Future<void> sendPost(String path, String hashMap) async {
        switch (hashMap) {
            case 'getArtifactData':
                var url = Uri.https(
                        'trivia.lifeupps.com', '/scripts/get_artifact_data', {'id': '1'});
                var response = await http.get(url);
                if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                    setState(() {
                        _scanBarcode = response.body;
                    });
                } else {
                    _scanBarcode = 'Response status: ${response.statusCode}';
                }
                print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
                print('Response body: ${response.body}');
                break;

            default:
                null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71268721/chromeproxyservice-failed-to-evaluate-expression) might be related.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem. It's because I'm trying to access the source thru another website (different IP/server) when debugging in a browser. meaning a should enable cross-origin resource thru header on PHP.